# Adding Character in front of a line which is having a specific string

Tags: bash

Example,

I have a file test with three lines like

```
Tell:you are the one
Great! that helped me
you:me are the one to go
```

In this file i like to search the string "you:me" , after finding it , It has to append # before it

which would be like this

```
Tell:you are the one
Great! that helped me
#you:me are the one to go
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I can see only one line. I'll edit one possible three lines, but I can't know which you mean, now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an awk alternative, just because:

```
awk '/you:me/ { print "#"$0 }'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do that with a regex:

```
sed 's/^you:me/#you:me/' thefile.txt
```

I assumed here that `you:me` is always at the begining of the line, otherwise if you want to match all `you:me`s:

```
sed 's/you:me/#you:me/g' thefile.txt
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.. But i try to append it to the same file , I am unable to do it.. This is what i get [10:23:00 host]>sed 's/^you:me/#you:me/' append_file
Tell:you are the one
Great! that helped me
#you:me are the one to go
[10:23:23 host]>sed 's/^you:me/#you:me/' append_file
[10:23:42 host]>cat append_file
Tell:you are the one
Great! that helped me
you:me are the one to go
[10:23:48 host]>sed 's/^you:me/#you:me/' append_file > append_file
[10:24:00 host]>cat append_file
[10:24:02 host]>ls -ltr append_file
-rwxr-xr-x 1 aselvan engr 0 Jan 28 10:24 append_file
[10:24:08 host]>

Comment: tried using sed -i " But no luck" my OS version is sunOS 5.10

Comment: sorry, but I don't get what you pasted… can you format it in your question?

Comment: I am trying the append it in the same file, unfortunately i am unable to do it. its something like this "[10:23:48 host]>sed 's/^you:me/#you:me/' append_file > append_file"  . Tried using "sed -i" as well that also didn't help

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed 's/you:me/#&/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggested, I would use sed. If, however, you are looking for a pure bash solution, use this:

```
while read line; do
    if [[ "$line" == "you:me"* ]]; then
        echo "#$line"
    else
        echo "$line"
    fi
done
```

As suggested by chepner, you could replace the if structure with a bash substitution:

```
while read line; do
    echo "${line/#you:me/#you:me}
done
```

As explained in the comment: The first hash is a flag indicating the match should be on the beginning of `$line`, the second is the literal hash we want to place in front of the line.

Comment: You can reduce the `if` statement to the redundant-looking `echo "${line/#you:me/#you:me}"` as well. The first `#` anchors the match to the beginning of the string; the second `#` is a literal character in the replacement test.

Comment: Of course, why didn't I think of bash substitutions. I'll add that, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
sed '/you:me/s/^/#/'
```

this will find a line containing `you:me`, no matter it is at beginning or middle, add a `#` at the beginning of the line

so

```
foo you:me bar -> #foo you:me bar
you:me foo -> #you:me foo
```